# Printing random Phone Numbers in a range

Tags: python-3.x, loops, range

I'm trying to print a large list of phone numbers. In this context, phone numbers have a format `(24)999999999`. (Parenthesis for clarity, they are incidental.) I need this list to be randomized, with certain constraints.

The first two digits must be between `11` and `24`,
the following two, which will be the the third and the fourth digits, must be between `67` and `99`.

This is what I've done so far:

```
ddd = list(range(11, 24))                                                                                                                                                                     
op = list(range(67, 99))                                                                                                                                                                      
list1 = list(range(100, 999))                                                                                                                                                                 
list2 = list(range(1234, 9999))                                                                                                                                                               
for d in ddd:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ddd = d                                                                                                                                                                                   
    #print(ddd)                                                                                                                                                                               
    for fixos in op:                           
        pre = fixos                            
        #print(pre)                            
        for l in list1:                       
            part1 = l                                                                         
            #print(part1)                                                                     
            for x in list2:   
                part2 = x                                                                    
                #print(part2)                                                                 
                #print(f"({ddd}) {pre}{l}-{l2}")                                              
                numbers = str(ddd) + str(pre) + str(l) + str(x)                              
                #print(numbers)                                                               
                requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

The `list1` and `list2` compose the rest of the number, which should be as random as possible.

However when I run the script it prints like this

```
numbers : 11671001000                                                                                                                                                      
numbers : 11671001001
```

It goes one by one. Sadly, that's not what I intended to do. How do I get it randomized?

Comment: So before the third and the fourth number, there are no restrictions on the fitht, sixth, seventh, etc. number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code it make 100,000 number also you can edit range 100,000 to your goal number

```
import random
ddd = list(range(11, 25))
op = list(range(67, 100))
for i in ddd:
    for j in op:
        beg=(str(i)+str(j))
        for p in range(100000):
            random_number=random.randint(1000000, 10000000)
            print(beg+str(random_number))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a different solution:

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import cycle
from pprint import pprint
country_code = list(range(11, 24))
operator_code = list(range(67, 99))
exchange_code = list(range(100, 999))
terminal_code = list(range(1234, 9999))


target_len = 100000
ls = set()
while len(ls) < target_len:
    shuffle(country_code)
    shuffle(operator_code)
    shuffle(exchange_code)
    shuffle(terminal_code)
    numbers = zip(cycle(country_code), cycle(operator_code), cycle(exchange_code), terminal_code)
    for c, o, e, t in numbers:
        ls.add(f"{c} {o}{e}-{t}")


pprint(ls)
print(len(ls))
# To randomize final output
ls = [i for i in ls]
shuffle(ls)
```

The output here is ordered because sets are ordered, but it makes some improvements on randomization using shuffle and cycle, and ensures you aren't repeating a number using the constraints of a `set`. Mostly I offer it as a way to think about the randomization differently - while selecting a random number with replacement (`randint`) is a route, `shuffle()` and `choice()` are both good ways to ensure randomness, and you can do things with `zip()` and `cycle()` to essentially create randomized streams that you're choosing from.

The real way to go about this would be to create a generator function - I'd have to think a little harder how to go about that, but it's also a possible solution here.